# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pack'

Tags: python

I want to add a video in my GUI application in Python in which new frame is read after the click of button. But I am getting this error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pack'.

When I uncomment the pack method then error goes away but a white blank window appears.

```
def show_vid(): 

     print cap
     print rdfile

     _ ,image = cap.read()

    cv2.imwrite("frame.jpg" , image)
    image=Image.open('F:\\MachineLearning\\\\frame.jpg')#creating a function
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    imglabel = Label(window, image=img)
    imglabel.grid(row=0 , column=0)#.pack().place(bordermode=OUTSIDE, x=10, y=100)
```

Answer (score 0):

this function call -

```
imglabel.grid(row = 0 , column = 0)
```

returned None. so when you try to call pack() on it, you get that error. simple, aint it?

to be even more accurate: I suspect grid() NEVER returns anything. Which is another way of saying it returns None. You're using that function incorrectly.

EDIT:

I know nothing about tkinter, but I believe you need to split your function call to 2 seperate ones:

```
imglabel.grid(row=0 , column=0)  //this returns nothing, so you can't call another function here.
imglabel.pack().place(bordermode=OUTSIDE, x=10, y=100)
```

Comment: its work fine but raises error... i also mentioned that when i uncomment the pack() statement and just use the grid() method... even then the frame is not uploaded but a blank white window appears

Comment: i removed that ... the error is removed but i am not gertting image on my gui now

Comment: dont remove the code - just split the call into two lines. could you edit the question to reflect the new code?

Comment: i edited  it... u can see the uncomment before pack..  i also tried to split the calls but its not working

Comment: what error are you getting after you've split into two lines?

Comment: i figured it out using another technique. first i made the reference of the image

Comment: great. I think you should erase this question since it probably is of little value to other users, but this is your call.

Answer (score 0):

Reminds me of what I just did:'
Thanks for the help guys!

```
def popup():
    """The popup windows opening"""
    window = Toplevel()
    label = tk.Toplevel
    label.Toplevel()
```

..became:

```
def popup():
    """The popup windows opening"""
    window = Toplevel()
    label = tk.Toplevel
```